# How to count an established successful outbound call

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, phone-state-listener

Is there an API which would tell whether an outbound call is placed successfully in Android?

I know that there are phonestatelisteners with telephony managers different states such as TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING, TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, etc but I couldn't find a direct API which would tell me whether an outbound placed call is really an outbound call or not meaning I would count an outbound call only if the called party has picked up the call & the call has actually taken place. It has to be a successfully placed outbound call. How do I count such outbound calls in Android?

One way I was thinking of is of putting a static int counter which will be incremented in TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK state, thus keeping track of a successful call but I'm not sure if this is the right & efficient approach. Is there any direct API or is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

i use like this on my project when incoming call is received and count is start.

```
mins = (TextView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.mins);
    secs = (TextView) new_view.findViewById(R.id.secs);
```

and use this textview in

```
mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            _sec++;
            if (_sec < 10) {
                secs.setText("0" + _sec);
            } else {
                secs.setText("" + _sec);
            }

            if (_sec >= 59) {
                _sec = 0;

                _min++;
                if (_min < 10) {
                    mins.setText("0" + _min);
                } else {
                    mins.setText("" + _min);
                }

            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    }, 2000)
```